# UITextField Cursor and Keyboard Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, xcode7-beta5, ios-9-beta5

My app was running fine on ios 8.4, but now after trying it on ios 9 beta, once the app is opened, the cursor on the UITextfield doesn't show up.

1. The keyboard doesn't come up. Shouldn't it come automatically?
2. The app works perfectly fine till ios8.4. Can some one help me out?
3. After one tap gesture on the UITextField, cursor doesn't show up at all.

Also, I tried checking the tintColor property as well as suggested by some users, but it is default blue.

Is there some specific change made in the way keyboard works on ios9?

A Situation - When I click on Login button, Alert message is displayed and then on pressing ok, the keyboard appears with a cursor but I can type only 1 character and suddenly the cursor and keyboard disappears. Then again, click on login, get the error message, cursor is available, type 1 character and cursor and keyboard disappears again.

Why is cursor on visible when tapped on a UITextField. This according to me must be a simple automatic thing. I have used resignFirstResponder and becomeFirstResponder too.

Anything to do with the Views here? For example, super view or something?

Thanks in advance!

Shrikant Kekane

Comment: your testing this on simulator or device?

Comment: when are you calling resignFirstResponder on textfield?

Comment: May be you forgot to set delegate for `UITextField` object.

Comment: please post your code.Do less talking.

Comment: Hello, I checked the code thrice again and found out a line resignFirstResponder in one of the methods, canPerformLogin in my class. Strangely, commenting out this line worked as expected on IOS 9 simulator. Not sure why this line was working previously. So finally, I just deleted the 1 line resignFirstResponder and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation you have described is not happening when I tried the same.

The steps I followed:

1. Drag and drop one `UITextField` in Storyboard.
2. Give it required constraints.
3. Build & Run.

Keyboard and cursor both work perfectly in iOS9 simulator.